# Making the paths (directories) in js code on an asp.net webforms master page work with pages on different levels from root directory

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

**I am doing something like the following in my master page:**

```
                <asp:Image data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom"
                    onmouseover="this.src='../Content/Images/icon-hover.png'"
                    onmousedown="this.src='../Content/Images/icon-hover.png'"
                    onmouseout="this.src='../Content/Images/icon.png'"
                    runat="server"
                    ImageUrl="../Content/Images/icon.png"></asp:Image>
```

However, I started noticing a problem when I put aspx pages that use this master page 2 levels down from the root directory:

**For example:**

Customers > Maintenance > Customers.aspx

`..Content/` only handles pages in paths that are one level such as:
Customers > Customers.aspx

Any suggestions to make this programmatic so I can do something similar to the ~ in JavaScript like I can in asp.net server-side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
onmouseover="this.src = getResolvedUrl('Content/Images/icon-hover.png')"
```

with the Javascript utility function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getResolvedUrl(url) {
        return '<%= ResolveUrl("~/") %>' + url;
    }
</script>
```